# How do I make the widths and lengths of an object automatically resize?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

**How do I make the widths and lengths of an object automatically resize?**

What I mean by this is that I'm trying to make my design responsive. The problem is that when a user resizes my app, the objects don't fill the empty spaces that are created (E.g, a box has the same problem).. I'm using Visual Studio and I'm not sure if this is a property or a programming issue..

Comment: Did you look at the properties Anchor and Dock?

Comment: please include the description of which controls you are using. Do you use containers such as a `TableLayout` or something similar ? you can also include a screenshot. This will make it easier for us to help you. The answers will be more precise and more related to your problem at hand

Comment: @Steve I'm using that. It only works for the placements of those objects. It helps them stay in the same place, but it doesn't automatically resize itself.

Comment: @Mong Zhu I don't use any containers or tables, I'm not sure if that would even help. As I said with Steve, I'm only using anchors and docks. I'm worried that someone might take my idea before I copyright my app so a screenshot isn't an option right now, Sorry.

Comment: a) anchoring on opposite sides __will__ grow or shrink the controls. b) responsive/fluid design on winforms is not well supported.. It should include repositioning as well as resizing; minsize is a way; also flowlayoutpanels are. c) _I'm worried that someone might take my idea before I copyright my app_ LOL, no offense meant, but can't you up with a dummy?

Comment: Also, the Dock property isn't great with Visual Studio. It's placements don't always match mine and Visual Studio normally resizes and replaces the objects to get the Dock property to work. When I had set it fill it just literally filled the app with this one box.

Comment: @Taw As big as I'm planning it makes copyright a big problem. Of course anchoring opposite sides do what you said, but when the app is nearly closed the object disappears. Still, docking works well with toolbars. b) I do believe you about this, but to me C# shows behavioral and functional things that I can use so maybe it can do a responsive design on winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In winforms, controls have a property `Dock`. You can set it to `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom` or `Fill`. If you set the `Dock` property for the various controls in your form, they will fill the available space whenever your form is resized.

Usually, the "main" control on your form will have a docking style of `Fill`, while the main menu toolbar will have `Top`, the status bar will have `Bottom` and so on. Play around with the `Dock` property until you get your form organized right.

You may also have controls that must keep a fixed size when their parent form is resized, but must align to one of the edges of the form. For this purpose, controls also have an `Anchor` property. Set it to `Left`, `Right`, `Top` or `Bottom`.